# Google geocode API returning wrong/empty values for Luxembourg zipcodes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I am making API calls for zips like L-4321, L-8287 etc.

Here are the urls.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4321%2CLU
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=postal_code%3A4321%7Ccountry%3ALU
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8287%2CLU
```

They are returning results for some places in USA. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The "return an empty string" response is not an expected behavior. It seems that the error lies in how you handle the response. If you are using the request directly on your browser it should at least return an [error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes) if it does not return a place.

Answer (score 0):

Those postal codes are just missing.

Of the 3 requests you tried, only this one is correct:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=postal_code%3A4321%7Ccountry%3ALU

It returns ZERO_RESULTS because there is no result that matches.

The other 2 requests find results that match the 4-digit number plus something that starts with "lu" (Luverne, Luz, etc.) ─ without the components=country:LU filter, there is no guarantee that results will be in Luxembourg.

Here's a request that does find a postal code in Luxembourg:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=postal_code%3A1717%7Ccountry%3ALU

Missing postal codes can be reported in Google Maps:
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en